# jQuery Form Validation on only Save button

Tags: jquery, forms, validation, button

I'm making a form where there is client-side validation with jQuery and then after submitting there is server-side validation with PHP. My problem is that by using $("form").submit(function (e) {}, when I click Cancel and Delete buttons, the validation messages also appear which shouldn't. I only want the validation to happen only when Save button is clicked. Is there another way I can do this? Thank you so much.
Below is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <!--Bootstrap CSS-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-y3tfxAZXuh4HwSYylfB+J125MxIs6mR5FOHamPBG064zB+AFeWH94NdvaCBm8qnd" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <title>Contact Form</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="container">

            <!--Display error message or success message, both won't happen same time-->
            <div id="error"><? echo $message; ?></div>

            <form method="post" id="myform">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="surname">Surname</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="surname" name="surname">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name">Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="address">Address</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="address" name="address">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="email">Email Address</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email">
                </div>

                <div class="form-check">
                    <label class="form-check-label">
                        <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" id="male" name="gender" value="Male"> Male
                  </label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-check">
                    <label class="form-check-label">
                        <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" id="female" name="gender" value="Female"> Female
                    </label>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="telephone">Telephone Number</label>
                    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="telephone" name="telephone">
                </div>
                
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="save" name="save">Save</button>
                <button class="btn btn-warning" id="cancel" name="cancel">Cancel</button>
                <button class="btn btn-success" id="list" name="list">List</button>

            </form>

        </div>

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vZ2WRJMwsjRMW/8U7i6PWi6AlO1L79snBrmgiDpgIWJ82z8eA5lenwvxbMV1PAh7" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        
        <script type="text/javascript">
            
            //When Save button is clicked, stop form submitting and run validation using jQuery
            $("form").submit(function (e) {

                var errorMessage = "";
  
                if($("#surname").val() == "") { 
                    errorMessage += "Please input a surname.<br>"  //If field is empty, append to errorMessage string
                }

                if($("#name").val() == "") { 
                    errorMessage += "Please input a name.<br>"
                }
                
                if($("#address").val() == "") { 
                    errorMessage += "Please input an address.<br>"
                }

                if($("#email").val() == "") { 
                    errorMessage += "Please input an email address.<br>"
                }

                if((!($('#male').prop('checked'))) && (!($('#female').prop('checked')))) {
                    errorMessage += " Please input a gender.<br>";
                }

                if($("telephone").val() == "") { 
                    errorMessage += "Please input a telephone number.<br>"
                }

                //If there is an error message
                if(errorMessage != "") {

                    //Set html to display error message 
                    $("#error").html('<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"><p>Please fill your form:</p>' + errorMessage + '</div>');
    
                    return false;  //Don't submit the form

                } else {
    
                    //Submit the form if no error
                    return true;
   
                }

            });
         
        </script>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You problem is that default type of a button is `submit` so by using `<button> Cancel </button>` you are also declaring this button to be a submit button, thus triggering the submit function of your form.

To solve this set the type of non submit buttons to `button` (you can leave out submit type since that is the default value)

Now you can handle the logic for your cancel and list button as you need:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" id="save" name="save">Save</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" id="cancel" name="cancel">Cancel</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="list" name="list">List</button>
```

```js
//When Save button is clicked, stop form submitting and run validation using jQuery
            $("form").submit(function (e) {

                var errorMessage = "";
  
                if($("#surname").val() == "") { 
                    errorMessage += "Please input a surname.<br>"  //If field is empty, append to errorMessage string
                }

                if($("#name").val() == "") { 
                    errorMessage += "Please input a name.<br>"
                }
                
                if($("#address").val() == "") { 
                    errorMessage += "Please input an address.<br>"
                }

                if($("#email").val() == "") { 
                    errorMessage += "Please input an email address.<br>"
                }

                if((!($('#male').prop('checked'))) && (!($('#female').prop('checked')))) {
                    errorMessage += " Please input a gender.<br>";
                }

                if($("telephone").val() == "") { 
                    errorMessage += "Please input a telephone number.<br>"
                }

                //If there is an error message
                if(errorMessage != "") {

                    //Set html to display error message 
                    $("#error").html('<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"><p>Please fill your form:</p>' + errorMessage + '</div>');
    
                    return false;  //Don't submit the form

                } else {
    
                    //Submit the form if no error
                    return true;
   
                }

            });
```

```html
<!--Bootstrap CSS-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-y3tfxAZXuh4HwSYylfB+J125MxIs6mR5FOHamPBG064zB+AFeWH94NdvaCBm8qnd" crossorigin="anonymous">


        <div class="container">

            <!--Display error message or success message, both won't happen same time-->
            <div id="error"><? echo $message; ?></div>

            <form method="post" id="myform">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="surname">Surname</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="surname" name="surname">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name">Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="address">Address</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="address" name="address">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="email">Email Address</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email">
                </div>

                <div class="form-check">
                    <label class="form-check-label">
                        <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" id="male" name="gender" value="Male"> Male
                  </label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-check">
                    <label class="form-check-label">
                        <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" id="female" name="gender" value="Female"> Female
                    </label>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="telephone">Telephone Number</label>
                    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="telephone" name="telephone">
                </div>
                
                <button class="btn btn-primary" id="save" name="save">Save</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" id="cancel" name="cancel">Cancel</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="list" name="list">List</button>

            </form>

        </div>

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks all for the replies. I wanted other buttons to submit as well because I need to send POST request and fetch data from database for the List button. What I did was replaced $("form").submit by $("#save").click to select only the save button and it works so other buttons when submitted will not have validation messages...

Answer (score -1):

If you like links do that

```html
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="save" name="save">Save</button>
<a href="#" class="btn btn-warning" id="cancel" name="cancel">Cancel</a>
<a href="#" class="btn btn-success" id="list" name="list">List</a>
```

If you like buttons. Just add type="button"

```html
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="save" name="save">Save</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" id="cancel" name="cancel">Cancel</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="list" name="list">List</button>
```

Because the default of every button is submit. This is why your error messages always are fired

Comment: Don't change buttons to links if they are buttons, that is just really bad advice.

Comment: I thought that if he want to cancel the form he is linking to another page and the List is not in a relation to the form. So that's why I'm linking.

Comment: If it is a link to another page, then sure, use a link. But I think these should be buttons. In case I'm wrong and OP really wants to link somewhere else, I apologize!

Comment: So lets see what he wants :-)